# Create Index if not exist with correct column order

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
define ITS_INDEX = BIG_INDX;
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  V_IND_NAME VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
    select index_name into V_IND_NAME from USER_INDEXES I where TABLE_NAME='ETL_TXN_Q'
       and (select count(1) from USER_IND_COLUMNS C where c.table_name = i.table_name and c.index_name = i.index_name) = 2
       and (select c.column_name from USER_IND_COLUMNS C where c.table_name = i.table_name and c.index_name = i.index_name and c.COLUMN_POSITION=1) = 'ETQ_SID'
       and (select c.column_name from USER_IND_COLUMNS C where c.table_name = i.table_name and c.index_name = i.index_name and c.COLUMN_POSITION=2) = 'PROCESSED_STATUS';
   
    IF V_IND_NAME = 'ETQ_ETQ_SID_PROCESSD_STATUS_UK' THEN
        IF count(V_IND_NAME)=2 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Index is correct and No Action Needed');
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Index exist with diff columns..Need to drop recreate');
            --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP index ETQ_ETQ_SID_PROCESSD_STATUS_UK';
            --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create unique index ETQ_ETQ_SID_PROCESSD_STATUS_UK on etl_txn_q (etq_sid,processed_status) tablespace &ITS_INDEX';
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('index with diff.name');
        --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP index ||V_IND_NAME';
        --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create unique index ETQ_ETQ_SID_PROCESSD_STATUS_UK on etl_txn_q (etq_sid,processed_status) tablespace &ITS_INDEX';
    ENDIF
END;
/
```

Comment: My requirement:
If index with correct name & for exact columns then OK,
else if index with exact column but with different name then drop & create
And index with correct name but with different columns set then also Drop & re-create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a procedure like the one below. By setting the first 3 variables, you can define any index by specifying the table name, index name, and columns.

```
DECLARE
    l_table_name           user_tables.table_name%TYPE := 'ETL_TXN_Q';
    l_correct_index_name   user_indexes.index_name%TYPE := 'ETQ_ETQ_SID_PROCESSD_STATUS_UK';
    l_columns              VARCHAR2 (4000) := 'ETQ_SID,PROCESSED_STATUS'; --Columns should be separated by commas, no spaces, in the order you want the index specified

    l_index_name           user_indexes.index_name%TYPE;
    l_index_exists         NUMBER;
    l_sql                  VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
      SELECT index_name
        INTO l_index_name
        FROM user_ind_columns
       WHERE table_name = UPPER (l_table_name)
    GROUP BY index_name
      HAVING LISTAGG (column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_position) = UPPER (l_columns);

    IF l_index_name = l_correct_index_name
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No changes needed. Index is correctly defined.');
        RETURN;
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Index is defined with the wrong name. Renaming index.');

        l_sql := 'ALTER INDEX ' || l_index_name || ' RENAME TO ' || l_correct_index_name;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_sql);

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    THEN
        --No index exists on the columns

        --Check if index name already exists
        SELECT CASE
                   WHEN EXISTS
                            (SELECT 1
                               FROM user_indexes
                              WHERE index_name = l_correct_index_name)
                   THEN
                       1
                   ELSE
                       0
               END
          INTO l_index_exists
          FROM DUAL;

        IF l_index_exists = 1
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                'Index exists, but on the wrong columns. Dropping existing index.');
            l_sql := 'DROP INDEX ' || l_correct_index_name;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_sql);

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
        END IF;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Creating index.');

        l_sql :=
               'CREATE INDEX '
            || l_correct_index_name
            || ' ON '
            || l_table_name
            || '('
            || l_columns
            || ')';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_sql);

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
END;
```

Comment: @jayreado, If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.